# iTunes Connect and iOS: Changing AppStore search name but not App name

Tags: ios, search, app-store, app-store-connect

Is there a way to change only the AppStore search name of the App but not the App.ipa name?

In other words, I would like to have an App that in the AppStore looks like "MyAppName: subtitle" but on the iPhone just like "MyAppName".

The reason for doing so is that, by providing the subtitle, I want to allow users to find "MyAppName" also by typing keywords included in the "subtitle".

EDIT: In other words, does the iTunes connect AppName have to be the same as the AppName of the XCode App bundle?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The name in iTunesConnect can be different than the .ipa file name. I do a similar trick for my own app, and it works just fine.

Comment: Cool. Need to wait 7 min before accepting the answer.

Comment: The name of the ipa file is irrelevant to any of this. It can be completely different from the name shown in iTunes and the name shown under the icon.

Answer (score 1):

Change the bundle display name in xcode to "MyAppName" then name it whatever you want in iTunes.   You may have to submit a new binary, and the name change might not be possible if you have iAd enable or in app purchases.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

3. Metadata (name, descriptions, ratings, rankings, etc.)

3.4 App names in iTunes Connect and as displayed on a device should be similar, so as not to cause confusion

So app will be rejected.